# LuaSSEQ problem

Tags: luatex, sseq

I am trying to compile a Lualatex file using the [luasseq package](http://www.few.vu.nl/~tilman/tex.html)

My minimum working example is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luasseq}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

When I run 'lualatex' on this it simply stops with a command window expecting me to type something in:

```
(/usr/local/apps/texlive2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/decorations/p
gflibrarydecorations.shapes.code.tex))
lua>
```

If I control-D (really all I can do)

```
! LuaTeX error <\directlua >:1: attempt to call global 'sseq_set_defaults' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
    <\directlua >:1: in main chunk.
l.332 \directlua0{sseq_set_defaults()}
```

Unsure what the problem is!

Comment: Confirmed with latest TL2011. I suspect a problem with either recent versions of `pgf` or `luatex`; you should contact the package author.

Comment: The error is not present in TeX Live 2015.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be linked to `kpse.find_file` not finding `luasseq.lua` and not complaining about it making the lua chunck keeping the focus forever.

See for example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\directlua0{dofile(kpse.find_file("luasseq.lua"))}
\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

A fix is to add the an explicit file type to `kpse.find_file`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\directlua0{dofile(kpse.find_file("luasseq.lua",'lua'))}
\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

You can locally edit your `luasseq.sty`, line 47.